# Why are WinForms controls disabled when the user zooms in Excel?

Tags: .net, winforms, excel, interop, vsto

When I open up an Excel spreadsheet with embedded WinForms controls, zoom in a bit (ctrl + scroll), and try to click on a control (tested with button and listbox), the following message is displayed in a popup:

> Windows Forms controls have been disabled because the document has been scaled. When zoom is returned to 100%, controls will reactivate.

What is the reasoning for making controls nonfunctional when zoomed in/out, and is there any way to work around this to keep the controls working?

I'm using .NET 3.5 and Excel 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because zooming uses a temporary image of the form in order to zoom it, and therefore there are no controls. When you return to the normal view, the image is discarded and you're back to the actual form, which has controls on it.

You can't work around this using normal Excel zoom functionality, because there's nothing to work around.

Comment: Looks like you're right: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178765%28VS.80%29.aspx (search for 'zoom').

Comment: Is the temporary-zoom-picture thing vsto-specific?

Comment: Not as far as I know; I'm pretty sure it's all Office-automation versions. (And it only makes sense, if you think about it - how would you zoom only one window in the entire OS and still keep everything functional in all windows?)

Answer (score 1):

There is some kind of workaround.
Instead inserting forms from the VS toolbox, I opened the workbook in excel and insert some ActiveX Controls, they don't come with that limitation.

Comment: This comment gave me the hint I needed to get my project going. The requirement was to allow zoom to work as well, and I wasn't able to find a workaround with embedding forms. Creating a custom ActiveX control and embedding that instead worked.